# Upload and unzip .zip file from E-Mail in Google Cloud Functions deleting .zip after completion nodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, node-modules

I am receiving an E-Mail containing one single .zip file. Right now im trying to upload it to GCS and handle (Bulk-Decompress) the file into its own folder. Running a Bulk Dataflow for such a small action seems overkill to me.

I was thinking about using the "unzip-stream" package but until now, i did not come up with an efficient solution to my problem.

Is it even possible to process a file like this in a Cloud-Function? Or is there no way without a dedicated server handling decompression and then uploading the content into GCS?

Heres my code:

```
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

// Node.js doesn't have a built-in multipart/form-data parsing library.
// Instead, we can use the 'busboy' library from NPM to parse these requests.
const Busboy = require('busboy');

exports.uploadZIPFile = (req, res) => {
  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    // Return a "method not allowed" error
    return res.status(405).end();
  }
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
  const tmpdir = os.tmpdir();

  for (a in req.headers) {
    console.log(`Header: ${a}`);
  }

  // This object will accumulate all the fields, keyed by their name
  const fields = {};

  // This code will process each non-file field in the form.
  busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    // TODO(developer): Process submitted field values here
    console.log(`Processed field ${fieldname}: ${val}.`);
    fields[fieldname] = val;
  });

  // This object will accumulate all the uploaded files, keyed by their name.
  const uploads = {};
  const fileWrites = [];

  // This code will process each file uploaded.
  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
    // Note: os.tmpdir() points to an in-memory file system on GCF
    // Thus, any files in it must fit in the instance's memory.

    console.log(`Processed file ${filename} - ${fieldname} - ${file}`);

    const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename);
    uploads[fieldname] = filepath;

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);

    file.pipe(writeStream);

    // File was processed by Busboy; wait for it to be written to disk.
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      file.on('end', () => {
        writeStream.end();
      });
      writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
      writeStream.on('error', reject);
    });

    fileWrites.push(promise);
  });

  // Triggered once all uploaded files are processed by Busboy.
  // We still need to wait for the disk writes (saves) to complete.
  busboy.on('finish', async () => {
    await Promise.all(fileWrites);

    // TODO(developer): Process saved files here
      for (const file in uploads) {
        
      async function upload2bucket() {
        // Uploads a local file to the bucket
        const bucketName = 'myBucket';
        const todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

        await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(uploads[file], {
          // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
          gzip: true,
          // By setting the option `destination`, you can change the name of the
          // object you are uploading to a bucket.
          destination:
            'zip-inbox/' + todayDate + '_' + uploads[file].substring(5),
          metadata: {
            // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
            // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
            // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
            cacheControl: 'no-cache',
          },
        });
        console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
      }
      if (uploads[file].endsWith('.zip')) {
        await upload2bucket();
      }

      console.log(`${file}: ${uploads[file]}`);
      //fs.unlinkSync(file);
    }
    res.status(200).send('Success');
  });

  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace your "do-everything" cloud function with several functions and create a pipeline with [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) messages or with [Google Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) (released in Jan, 2021).

I also recommend to use [firebase-functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions) package to simplify cloud functions definitions.

Pipeline could be like this:

1. Create and schedule a function which gets attachments from the mailbox and uploads them to Google Storage. After each attachment has been uploaded it sends a PubSub message with the filepath payload to the next step.
2. Create another function which executes on message from PubSub and unpacks uploaded earlier file.

Note: a function can execute for not more than 9 minutes. Split the function if it takes longer than the limit.

Here is a pseudo code for the proposed pipeline:

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {PubSub} from '@google-cloud/pubsub';

const REGION = 'your-google-cloud-region'; // e.g. europe-west1
const PUBSUB_TOPIC_UNPACK_ZIP = 'your-topic-name-for-step-2';

/**
 * Step 1.
 */
exports.getFromEmailAndUploadToStorage = functions
  .region(REGION)
  .runWith({
    memory: '256MB',
    timeoutSeconds: 540, // Max execution duration is 9 minutes
    maxInstances: 1
  })
  .pubsub
  .schedule('every 15 minutes')
  .timeZone('Asia/Vladivostok')
  .onRun(async _ => {
    const filepath = await yourLogicToFetchEmailAndUploadToStorage();
    if (filepath) {
      const messagePayload = {filepath};
      console.log('Publishing message to the topic:', PUBSUB_TOPIC_UNPACK_ZIP);
      console.log('Payload:', JSON.stringify(messagePayload));
      await new PubSub().topic(PUBSUB_TOPIC_UNPACK_ZIP).publishMessage({
        json: messagePayload
      });
    }
  });

/**
 * Step 2.
 */
exports.unzipFilesInStorage = functions
  .region(REGION)
  .runWith({
    memory: '256MB',
    timeoutSeconds: 540, // Max execution duration is 9 minutes
    maxInstances: 1
  })
  .pubsub
  .topic(PUBSUB_TOPIC_UNPACK_ZIP )
  .onPublish(async (message, context) => {
    const {filepath} = message?.json;
    if (!filepath) {
      throw new Error('filepath is not set.');
    }

    // your unzip logic here.
    // after unzipping you can pipe the results further via PubSub messages.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions are great for small tasks, which take little time. When you have a similar requirement - you want to spin an instance for a unit of work only when needed, but cannot predict the time to execute it, I suggest using Cloud Run, have a look at this [use case](https://cloud.google.com/run#section-10)

Comment: This process is completely predictable. See https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits . 9 minutes is an enermous amount of time. Email servers have rigid limits for attachments and a letter size around 10-20-30 megs. Each email message attachment donwload and upload it to Google Storage can't/shouldn't take longer than 9 minutes. Each zip of such size also can't/shouldn't take longer than 9 minutes to unpack. Just divide, compose a pipeline and conquer.